# When does F(electrical)=qE=F(magnetic)=qvB hold?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

**Under what circumstances can I set the force due to an electrical field, $F=qE$ equal to the force due to a magnetic field $F=qVB$?**

---

For some context:

The following question asks to solve for velocity, which is done by rearranging $F=qE=F=qVB$, but I am unsure which condition in the question allows me to equate the two.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the answer by simple dimensional analysis in this case, if you just have to discriminate between the four. Of those, just $E/B_1$ has the dimension of a velocity.

If you want to solve this problem the honest way, think about that: a particle enters with velocity $v$ through hole $S_1$, with the velocity orthogonal to the plates. It meets an electric field $E$ that is orthogonal to the direction of motion, and a magnetic field $B_1$ that is orthogonal to both the direction of motion and the electric field.

You are assuming that the particles manage to reach the hole, so we don't want deviations. $E$ tends to bring the particle to the $M$ and $N$ plates but, due to the positioning of the field $B_1$ (orthogonal to $v$ and $E$), the magnetic force will entirely lie in $E$'s direction, and be opposite to it if the appropriate verse of the magnetic field is chosen.

Thus, you have an electrical force $QE$ deviating the particle, and a magnetic force $QvB_1$ to deviate it the other way. Now you put them equal because you want them to exit the hole: this gives you the velocity.

But, in truth, you have the same velocity of entrance (due to the fact that the forces are null), so the question really makes little sense. A better way to posing the question would have been something like

"In a beam with electrically charged particles of multiple velocities, we tune the electric and magnetic fields to $E$ and $B_1$. What velocities must the particles have to pass through slit $S_3$?"

I think that posing questions in a more practical way is good for understanding.